# How To get the Index of each element of the DOM array made by the querySelectorAll() method (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, json

```
let var = document.querySelectoAll('.class')

console.log(var) = Array[15]
```

(Array consists of 15 elements)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Can you elaborate on the problem and in what way your attempt isn't working as expected?

Comment: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array.

Comment: Try not to use Dom.methods.
Make an array and loop in render and get every selector index by map.key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NodeList.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/entries) for that:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
for (const [index, node] of nodes.entries()) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
const elementArray = Array.from(elements);

elementArray.forEach((element, index) => {
console.log(`Index: ${index}, Element:`, element);
});